# dynamically generate file with last day of previous month in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I need to generate a file with last day of month using SSIS. I am getting it using SQL.

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = '03/21/2013'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)),@mydate),112) 
--20130228
```

I dont know how to put it in SSIS expression in connection manager.
The file name will be like `'ABC_20130228.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the date to a variable in SSIS, then pass that variable to a script task that builds the file name and puts that in an output variable.  Then you can assign the output variable in the ConnectionString property under the Expressions property group in the properties for the Connection Manager for that output file to use the variable's value as your file name.

to Summarize:

1. Use a script task and pass the date to use in the file name to it as a read only variable as type string to make it easier to manipulate.
2. Assign a read/write variable to the script task to store your file name.
3. Create the file name in the script task.
    Variables named:  User::DataFile, User::MaxDate
   ie String DataFileName;
    String DateToUse;

   DateToUse= (String) Dts.Variables["MaxDate"].value;
    DataFileName="ABC_"+Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDateTime(DateToUse)).Year)+Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDateTime(DateToUse)).Month)+Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDateTime(DateToUse)).Day)+".txt";
    Dts.Variables["DataFile"].value=DataFileName;
4. Assign the variable in the Expression sections of the properties for the Connection Manager to the CONNECTIONSTRING property.

That should do it.  If you need a particular path, then that would be concatenated onto the property and variable in step 4.

Comment: You could do it that way.  I just used this code because I had to create multiple filenames for other reasons as well and I had to do some other manipulation.  I extracted the naming part out of that routine.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a script task? Why not use the expression described here:

[Add datestamp to a .txt file in an SSIS Package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372009/add-datestamp-to-a-txt-file-in-an-ssis-package)